# Angular 8 routerLinkActive doesn't work with ng-template

Tags: angular

I'm having trouble with the routerLinkActive attribute in angular 8. When rendering a link with the attribute inside an ng-template the routerLinkActive class is not applied to the parent element when the link is active. I.e...

```
<div routerLinkActive="active2">
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="test" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{link: '/home', name: 'Home'}"></ng-container> |
</div>

<ng-template #test let-link="link" let-name="name">
  <a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="[link]">{{name}}</a>
</ng-template>
```

Seems to have stopped working since I updated to Angular 8.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routelinkactive-broken-template)

Comment: For anyone interested, I feel like this is a bug so I've raised the issue here...

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31930

Answer (score 1):

check the below solution

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routelinkactive-broken-template-g3cxxt

I have merged 2 css classes into one

Comment: Thanks for that but I need the class to be applied to the parent element. I've changed my example to more accurately reflect my issue.